# Using 2 WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am trying to do two WHERE clauses after each other and its not displaying what I want.

`SELECT FROM users LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total AND $table2.date = CURDATE() WHERE users.value = '$value' WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales'";`

I want to display all users that match what is stored in $value, along with this I also want all users that have a user value of 'marketing' OR 'sales'. Currently it is displaying all users, even ones that don't have the correct value in $variable. It looks like it is grouping my two WHERE clauses together but I want them to be separate. Any thoughts?

Comment: you don't need to use two where clauses for this,just add another condition with 'and' like:-WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales' and users.value = '$value'  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems in your query I fixed. You can't use two `where` clauses. In this specific case, use `in` to select all rows where one field can be one of a specific list:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   users
 LEFT
 JOIN   table2
 on     users.user = table2.total
 AND    table2.date = CURDATE()
 WHERE  users.value = '$value'
 AND    users.user in ( 'marketing', 'sales' )
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add more conditions concatenating them by the 'AND' keyword. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN table2 on
     users.user = table2.total AND
     table2.date = CURDATE()
WHERE
  users.value = '$value' AND
  (users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales')
```

But I think this could be a bit easier to read and maybe meeting better your requirements:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN table2 on
  users.user = table2.total
WHERE
  users.value = '$value' AND
  users.user in ('marketing', 'sales') AND
  table2.date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: The last one's not equivalent - you're going to implicitly change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `(INNER) JOIN`.

Comment: Yes. I thought maybe this is what OP wanted really. But it was a guess only.